# Sitecore Fast Query w/ Standard Values for Checkbox Fields

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have Standard Values defined for a template I call Lawyer. In the standard values, the 'IsActive' property of the Lawyer is set to checked or 'on'.

My problem arises when I query my lawyers against whether or not they are active.

In the first configuration, I use a normal Sitecore query and get all the results I expect back.

### [image: Regular Sitecore Query]

When I switch this query to a fast query, I get the following results.
[image]

Edward Bailey is now missing because he is the only lawyer who has not had his IsActive box manually modified from his defaults.

Why does Sitecore query behave this way, and is there a good work-around? (Besides not using fast query of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Sitecore Fast Query does not and cannot query based on standard values. I would suggest switching to Sitecore.Search/Lucene.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query.pdf

Limitations of Sitecore Fast Query include:

- Limited axes and special attributes in queries
- You cannot put a special attribute at the start of a condition
- Does not account for context language
- Does not support sorting
- Does not support inherited standard values or clone values, or proxy items
- Does not support functions, operators, or sub-queries
- Does not support piping of paths into one expression

Comment: That is quite unfortunate. Thank you, though.